# How to prove that $a^{2^n} - 1$ is divisible by $4\cdot2^n$ by induction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction, exponentiation

Given that $a$ is any odd number and $n$ is any integer
I got to $(2k + 3)^{2^k}\cdot(2k + 3)^{2^k} - 1$ at the $(k+1)$-th step.

Comment: I guess you have $n \geq 1$. You should specify this. Otherwise for $n=0$ you are saying that $a-1$ is always divisible by $4$, which is false.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$$\frac{a^{2^{n+1}}-1}{a^{2^n}-1}=a^{2^n}+1$$ which is even.

Comment: I feel stupid, I have no idea where to go from here

Comment: @JJP_SWFC Suppose that $a^{2^n}-1$ is divisible by $4\cdot 2^n$. Then $a^{2^{n+1}}-1$ is an even number times something that is divisible by $4\cdot 2^n$ so it is divisible by $4\cdot 2^{n+1}$. Do you have further questions?

Answer (score 1):

For $n=1$ this is obvious, because $a^2-1=(a-1)(a+1)$, and both factors are even, so $2^2 = 4\cdot 2^0$ divides $a^2-1$.

Assume this is true for $n$, so $4\cdot 2^n$ divides $a^{2^n}-1$. Then
\begin{align*}
a^{2^{n+1}}-1 & = a^{2^n\cdot2}-1 \\
& = (a^{2^n}-1)(a^{2^n}+1) \\
& = 4\cdot 2^n \cdot k\cdot(a^{2^n}+1),
\end{align*}
for $k$ an integer. But now $a^{2^n}$ is odd, so $a^{2^n}+1$ is even, hence $a^{2^n}+1 = 2h$ for $h$ an integer. Therefore
$$a^{2^{n+1}}-1 = 4\cdot 2^n \cdot k \cdot 2h = 4\cdot 2^{n+1} \cdot hk$$
and the claim follows.